# How to prove: $\frac{1+x}{2(x^3-1)}\leq\frac{9}{13x^2}$ for $x\geq 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to prove

$$\frac{1+x}{2(x^3-1)}\leq\frac{9}{13x^2},\;\;\;\text{ where }\;x\geq 3\;\;?$$

I can only get an upper bound as:

$$\frac{1+x}{2(x^3-1)}\leq\frac{1}{13}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x > 1$ you want to prove that $$13x^2+13x^3 \leq 18 x^3-18$$ *i.e*, you want to prove that $5x^3-13x^2-18 \geq 0$.

But $$5x^3-13x^2-18=(x-3)(5x^2+2x+6)$$ and the discriminant of $5x^2+2x+6$ is $\Delta=4-120 = -116 < 0$,

which shows that $\;5x^2+2x+6\;$ has constant sign, and is positive (take, e.g. $x=0$).

Therefore if $$x \geq 3, \;\; 5x^3-13x^2-18 \geq 0.$$

Comment: I hope, dear fonfonx, I didn't upset you with my edits.  It was all formatting, and mostly spacing;  I like your answer, and simply wanted to present your work well.

Comment: Very careful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Oops, @fonfonx  I meant to say that *I hope* I didn't upset you with my edits.

Comment: @amWhy you didn't :) thanks for improving the formatting btw

Answer (score 1):

You need to show $(1+x)(13x^3)\leq 9\times 2(x^3-1)$ which simplifies to show that $$5x^3-13x^2-18\geq 0$$

**The problem:**

> If $x\geq 3$, prove that $5x^3-13x^2-18\geq 0$

Let $f(x)=5x^3-13x^2-18$. Note that $f(3)=0$

$f'(x)=15x^2-26x=x(15x-26)>0$ when $x\geq 3$. Hence $f$ is strictly increasing function.

Then if $x\geq 3$, $f(x)\geq f(3)$. Hence $$5x^3-13x^2-18\geq 0\space\space\space\blacksquare$$

Comment: Nice approach here, manmaid. A great way to use calculus to solve this.  I'm not sure whether the asker will understand what $f'$ means, nor anything about derivatives (simply noting the tags they used).  But this is certainly useful to keep around for those encountering the question and also know derivatives of functions, and the info they provide.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, I did not see tags actually (I will notice next time, thanks for that too). Usually when OP do not specify a process I try do it in easier way than the other solution on that page, that's all. Secondly, if he does not know derivative and if someday if he learns that he may come back here and see this solution! Thirdly, if someone post this problem again and says "how to solve this problem using calculus" or something like that you can point here... and mark that post as duplicate.

Comment: Oh, please understand that I upvoted your post.  I like it; It is and will be useful to many current/future users (and sometimes users aren't the smartest when choosing tags, anyway.)  The main point of my comment was meant to be "good job"... It is a fine post, and more original that the others here! :-)

Comment: Oh! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Get x on one side and bring the expressions to a common denominator

Answer (score 0):

your inequality $$\frac{1+x}{2(x^3-1)}\le \frac{9}{15x^2}$$ is equivalent to
$$0\le 5x^3-13x^2-18=(x-3)(5x^2+2x+6)$$ which is true since we have $$x\geq 3$$